# QField -- using Python init functions

Tags: qgis, python, qfield

We are using the field mapping application QField with QGIS 2.18 for on-site data collection.

I've looked through the [documentation](http://www.qfield.org/docs/installation-guide/index.html) and am still unsure, so am bring this question here: Is it possible to use python scripts using the python init function specification in the layer field properties?

I currently use a script to automatically assign object modification date and time. I am looking use this, because as far as I can tell, the now() function only works when the object is created. Updating existing points does not update the now() variable.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without Python support.

Add the expression `now()` to the field and activate "apply default value on update".

Unfortunately, there is currently no Python support for QField.

See [this anwer [image]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211154/9839) .