# Automatically assigning attributes when defining one attribute in table using QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3

If it is possible to assign attributes when you define one attribute in a table, like automatic selection additional Attributes, then how is it done?

Comment: If you're asking how to set a default value for an attribute, this will help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211120/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-attributes-in-shapefiles

Comment: If you're asking how to edit the attributes of multiple features simultaneously, try this: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#editing-multiple-fields