# Automatically updating feature area in the attribute table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, features, update, measurements

How can I write an expression to update the area of polygons and lengths of features automatically as well as the sum of the areas and lengths? I am using QGIS 3.16.7 and the data format is OGR library.

Comment: What GIS Software are you using?

Comment: You also need to specify the data format in the Question, since the answer differs by format.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume there was created a feature and calculated an `"area"` attribute for it

[image: input]

For catching changes done to that feature i.e. automatically updating the area, please set up some defaults through `Right-mouse click > Properties > Attribute Form > Fields > area > Defaults`

[image: settings]

I set `$area` as the *'Default value'* as well as ticked the *'Apply default value on update'* and clicked <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

So, now after modifying the feature's geometry, its area attribute will be updated automatically.

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [Setting default value for attributes in shapefiles using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211120/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-attributes-in-shapefiles-in-qgis)
- [QGIS Training Manual » 5.3.3. Follow Along: Setting Form Field Types](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html#moderate-fa-setting-form-field-types)

Comment: To add to this question, can I obtain an updated attribute value without modifying its geometry? By that I mean copying the style from one shp into another to duplicate the same Attributes Form properties.