# Area/perimeter calculations in table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, area

In ArcView3.2 I used Xtools a lot, just click and it calculated area/perimeter for every polygon, in QGIS I am choosing column and write $area after the "**E**psilon" + update.

Is there some simple way for a beginner like me to simplify the calculus-command to a button or keyboard-shortcut

Comment: Check some details about ["Forms"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html#ls-forms), here an example of using it: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/398215/automatically-updating-the-attribute-table. I hope it is what you needed

Comment: You might want to check out the "Calculate geometry" plugin

Comment: Thanks Tara/Micha that was what i needed

Comment: Why is the area result different between the plug in and the $area

Comment: plugin                         $area
BLOCKID                                                AREA                         AREA
65584693859                                    40781.697998046875 40814.183
65584696138                                        28063.176025390625 28085.494
65584693061                                         22589.4482421875         22607.372
65584691338                                         3985.118408203125 3988.303
65584691643                                     1794.15185546875         1795.561              
 the two columns i the right is in squaremeters

Comment: Can you please add more clarity?

Comment: (I am sorry for flooding the forum) What do you need, the shapefile? I was adding a chart but it looks like it didnt work

Comment: i think i choose the wrong ellipsoid, now its the (almost) same

Answer (score 1):

Simply choose the [`Identify Features`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#identify)-icon, click on any feature and get the information you want from the section `(derived)` - see screenshot (be aware to use an appropriate CRS to get meaningful values):

[image]