# Set default value based on multiple fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression, select

I have a layer with a relate table (1-M) with three columns (fk_id, date, comment).

| fid | fk_id | date | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | 2021-02-03 | Comment 1 |
| 2 | 02 | 2021-02-05 | Comment 2 |
| 3 | 02 | 2021-03-02 | Comment 3 |
| 4 | 02 | 2021-03-25 | Comment 4 |
| 5 | 03 | 2021-01-11 | Comment 5 |

I have also created a custom form for the layer and table.

[image: Custom form]

What I need is when I add a new record to the related table, the default comment must be the same as the last date for that `fk_id`.

So, in this example, if I create a new record in the related table using the form, the comment should be `Comment 4`.

I'm looking around the expression builder but I have no idea how to do this selection.

Anyone could give me a tip of how can I set this default?

Comment: Just to check I got this right: Based on your ID, you want to grab the comment of the newest of the already existing features with the same ID?

Comment: That's right (I guess I didn't explain myself well in the question).

Comment: It's always tricky to explain familiar issue to others ;-) anyway, to my knowledge it is not possible to automatically base one attribute of a new feature on something you're entering while creating that feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a new record to the related table, with the default comment the same as the last date for that attribute, please set up some defaults through `RMC > Properties > Attribute Form > Fields > date > Defaults`

[image: settings]

I set `map_get(attributes(get_feature_by_id(@layer, maximum("fid"))), 'date')` as the *'Default value'* as well as ticked the *'Apply default value on update'* and clicked <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

So, now after adding a new feature it will possess the date of the last feature.

Mind that [`maximum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#maximum) function also includes `group_by` argument.

For the example of the question, a working expression could be:

`map_get(attributes(get_feature_by_id(@layer, maximum("fid", group_by:="fk_id"))), 'comment')`

---

**References:**

- [How to set a default value for attributes in shapefiles in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211120/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-attributes-in-shapefiles-in-qgis)
- [QGIS Training Manual » 5.3.3. Follow Along: Setting Form Field Types](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html#moderate-fa-setting-form-field-types)

Comment: Thanks Taras, I used your expression using group_by for maximum(): `map_get(attributes(get_feature_by_id(@layer, maximum(fid, fk_id))), 'comment')`