# How to autopopulate cell every time a new feature is created in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

So I am working on a project with QGIS where every time I place a new point, I want the value for the area field to be automatically set to 32 sq ft rather than me have to use the field calculator every time I add a new feature. However, I have been struggling to figure out how to do this?

Comment: did you search the forum already? for example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211154/87346

Answer (score 3):

Just set default value for this field.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the `Settings| Options | Digitization` section options it is possible to set the repetition of the entered values.
So it would be enough to enter 32 the first time, then it would always repeat.

[image]