# Adding features based on existing attribute information in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am digitizing features and would like to add them based on the existing attributes/categorized field so that I digitize without having to go add attributes manually by either selecting them and populating the field. In ArcGIS, this is durable, however, I cannot find the same in QGIS. The idea is that, when I digitize for instance the rivers, I add them as such, and when I would like to add Dams, I also add them as such in the same shapefile (one field) categorized based on the field of interest with different attributes/description.
[image]

Comment: You can use Default values, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211120/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-attributes-in-shapefiles-in-qgis