# Automatically fill table with Geographic coordinates if shapefile is in UTM?

Tags: field-calculator, coordinates, utm, qgis-2.18

I have a shapefile of points in Qgis 2.18. I created the points by direct click on a map, using the digitizing tool. Now I need to fill the 2 columns "Lat" and "Long" in the attribute table with Geographic coordinates (DD MM.mmm).

The shapefile is in Utm. I used the instructions found here: [How to automatically fill a lat/long in attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101956/how-to-automatically-fill-a-lat-long-in-attribute-table).

But when I try to use the Field calculator, the columns are filled with Lat and Long values referred to UTM. Even when I set the Project properties to Geographic, the Field calculator calculate always UTM coordinate to fill the columns.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please [edit] your question to include more information, such as what GIS software you're using, and what actual steps you've followed in your attempts.

Comment: Do you mean you need to transform to epsg 4326? Like I can use `x(transform($geometry,'epsg:27700','epsg:4326'))` to get the X coordinate for my UK Grid data?

Comment: Yes, my shapefile is in EPSG32632 and I need, in the table, the coordinates in EPSG 4326. Your script works (thanks!) but still I get DD.dddd while I need DD MM.mmm